# When I am creating a build with "npm run build" command I got this error, how to fix this

Tags: reactjs, build

When I am creating a build with "npm run build" command I got this error, how to fix this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r8wo.png), Please check the image for error.
I am have writing react.js code but when I try to create a build I got this error I think in Webpack please suggest the solution for this

Here is the full image with code and error in theme.scss
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvYQL.png)

Comment: as the message states you have an error in src/assets/scss/theme.scss. you should probably attach it if you want help

Comment: I have attached an image of the error

Comment: @Anton I have added the code of theme.scss file please check and guide me

Comment: show your `--bs-primary-rgb` variable

Comment: also which bootstrap version are you using

Comment: I am using bootstrap 5.1.1

Comment: $link-color: rgba(var(--bs-primary-rgb), 1); 
this is the variable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.